# jQuery hide and show containers with clicks on differend values

Tags: jquery

I want only to hide and show .container with jQuery clicks on the right input fields.

How can i show only first and second container. If I click on Rating 2 Stars and more, price 2.50 and Delivery charges 4.00$ ?

First and second container should only be visible. But if i click on "4 Stars and more" the second container should appear.

If i click again "3 Stars and more" all should disappear. If i click accessorily Price 3.45$ and Dalivery charges 5.00$ last container should be visible.

My code example

```html
<body>
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="box">
     <p>Rating</p>
        <label for="rat0"><input type="radio" name="rating" id="ra0t" value="1"> 1 Star</label>
        <label for="rat1"><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rat1" value="2"> 2 Stars and more</label>
        <label for="rat2"><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rat2" value="3"> 3 Stars and more</label>
        <label for="rat3"><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rat3" value="4"> 4 Stars and more</label>
        <label for="rat4"><input type="radio" name="rating" id="rat4" value="5"> 5 Stars and more</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
     <p>Price</p>
        <label for="prc0"><input type="radio" name="price" id="prc0" value="0"> No matter</label>
        <label for="prc1"><input type="radio" name="price" id="prc1" value="1.00"> 1.00$</label>
        <label for="prc2"><input type="radio" name="price" id="prc2" value="2.50"> 2.50$</label>
        <label for="prc3"><input type="radio" name="price" id="prc3" value="3.00"> 3.00$</label>
        <label for="prc4"><input type="radio" name="price" id="prc4" value="3.45"> 3.45$</label>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <p>Delivery charges</p>
        <label for="del0"><input type="radio" name="delcha" id="del0" value="1"> 1.00$</label>
        <label for="del1"><input type="radio" name="delcha" id="del1" value="2"> 2.00$</label>
        <label for="del2"><input type="radio" name="delcha" id="del2" value="3"> 3.00$</label>
        <label for="del3"><input type="radio" name="delcha" id="del3" value="4"> 4.00$</label>
        <label for="del4"><input type="radio" name="delcha" id="del4" value="5"> 5.00$</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="container" data-rating="4" data-price="2.50" data-delcha="4.00">
     <p>First container</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" data-rating="2" data-price="2.50" data-delcha="4.00">
     <p>Second container</p>
    </div>
    <div class="container" data-rating="3" data-price="3.45" data-delcha="5.00">
     <p>Last container</p>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(window).load(function () {
      $("#navigation > .box > label > input").click(function () {
                
          var get_value = $(this).val(); // Get a value from input field
        
          if (get_value !== "") {
           // ??
          }
        
          if (get_value == "0") {
            $("#content > .container").show();
            }
           });
)};
 </script>

</body>
```

Comment: If you run your snippet there is a syntax error which needs addressing

Comment: Here is a start: `$(function() {
  $("#navigation > .box > label > input").click(function() {
    $("#content > .container").hide();
    var get_value = $(this).val(); 
    $("#content > .container").eq(get_value-1).show();
  });
});`